# How to trigger power bank to output 12V?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, mosfet, usb

I have a  power bank that can output 5V fast charge or, 5V 9V or 12V regular charge.

https://www.banggood.com/JUWEI-QC2_03_0-Automatic-USB-Tester-Voltage-Ammeter-Quick-Charger-Power-Bank-Voltage-Trigger-p-1193891.html?gmcCountry=US&currency=USD&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_elc&utm_content=frank&utm_campaign=pla-elc2-rm-mail-us-pc-0801&gclid=Cj0KCQiA7briBRD7ARIsABhX8aB96Xvey2jcVyxomApEos681neoBoqblU7PtxHJ7P-89D2S6meBIr4aApFfEALw_wcB&cur_warehouse=CN
I am using this voltage trigger to get the 12V output desired but I have a special condition.

The power bank will be secured away and I will not be able to access the buttons to change it to the mode needed.
I soldered a wire to the positive and negative side  of the "up" button on the voltage trigger. I did the same for the "mode" button as well.

I wrote a small program that reads the Voltage output of the power bank using a voltage divider to have the ~12V match the top voltage that the arduino can read. When the power is not at the right setting it sends a signal to an N-channel MOSFET to simulate the button being clicked and change the voltage level.

When I touch the positive and negative wires that I soldered to the "up" button for about 700ms the voltage  output changes. I've tried a HIGH pulse and a LOW pulse at different lengths between 700 -1500 ms with the N-channel MOSFET that doesn't quite work.

The problem is that sometimes the voltage trigger toggles between the power levels without any influence. Even when all wires are disconnected and its just the power bank and the trigger. That makes it difficult/impossible for me to be sure  that my program is running correctly, or that I can rely on it to set the output to 12V

What options do I have to get  the power bank to output 12V without needing to manually do anything?

Comment: You need to find out what protocol is being used. I'd suggest a logic analyzer and a known device (mobile phone) that can speak the protocol.

Comment: @Indraneel, the link to "trigger tool" says it is QC 2.0 and QC 3.0.

Comment: @Ale..chenski The Ti datasheet does not mention Qualcomm. Quick Charge is a "proprietary" Qualcomm technology. I could not find the QC 2.0 timings on the web (after a "Quick" search). The trigger tool description and spec says it is QC 2.0 (3.0 only in (dubious) headline). [It is 2.0, because 3.0 is continuously variable to 20 V)

Comment: You might also want to show us the circuit of the trigger module, because we don't have it (hopefully it is a 2 layer PCB). Are the voltage up/down switches connecting to ground? Do you have pull up resistors for the mosfet drains (without which it will likely not work)? What is the leakage current for your mosfets?

Comment: @Indraneel, the OP already posted exactly the same question about a year ago, and it was closed as duplicate. This one is a duplicate of a closed duplicate. Yes, QC is undisclosed protocol, so only indirect information from few supporting IC is available. The other duplicate has some useful links.

Comment: @Ale..chenski duplicate of a duplicate by the same OP? Yikes! You're right!

Comment: Im sorry for the duplicate I thought this question was a little different since I was trying to manipulate the voltage trigger device. So it seems I should just scrap the USB voltage trigger device and mimic the protocol over the d+ and d- ?
Seems from the example of an answer from the link mentioned that (just to clarify) I would apply ~1V for  1.25 seconds and ground the d- for the same amount of time, then apply 0.6V to both d- and d+ continuously for 12V (according to the table)?